# Why top position is different in Internet Explorer 11 and Safari / Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

When I use the `top` property in Safari and Chrome, on Apple it gives me according to my specification. But in Internet Explorer, it goes up 32 pixels. For example, I used:

```
top: 362px;
```

In IE 11, this goes up 23 pixels. If I use 
     top: 385px;

then it works fine in IE, but goes down 23px in other browsers.

Any help will be appreciated.

```css
.captn {
  position: relative;
  top: 362px;
  padding: 14.5px 0 14.5px 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 300;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: .9;
}
```

```html
<div id="caption" class="captn"></div>
```

Comment: I think this seems to me a media query problem, because I am working  in windows 1920 x 1080 resolution and in Mac 1440 x 900.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Also I am using media query.